# No page number, how to do?

Tags: pdftex, page-numbering

I have these packages, but I have no numeration of pages how to get page numbers?

```
 \documentclass[leqn]{arabart}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{arabtex}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs}
 \usepackage{fancybox}
 \novocalize \ligsfalse \setarab
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \textwidth=18truecm
 \textheight=26truecm 
 \hoffset=-4truecm 
 \voffset=-3.5truecm \ligsfalse \mathchardef\cap="225C \arabfootnotes
 \renewcommand{\l}{\mathscr{L}}
 \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern 2pt
 \newcommand{\supp}{{\rm supp}\;}
 \hfill\rule[2pt]{7truecm}{0.4pt} }
 \newcount\adad \adad=0
 \newcommand{\raqm}{\global\advance\adad by 1{\number\adad}}
\begin{document}    
\textcolor{red}{[1]}    
\newpage     
\LR{hello}     
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not use quote formatting, use the backticks or CTRL - K formatting here.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sorry i don't know what is all this ?

Comment: The code does not compile. Anyway, tinkering with `\hoffset` and `\textheight` like that is probably the cause: the page number most likely goes beyond the bottom of the page.

Comment: @egreg i edited the question now it works but no number of page

Comment: @Vrouvrou Remove the unnecessary blank lines, please. And also the wrong definitions, possibly, like the one of `\tmryn`.

Comment: i  edited the question @egreg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page number is printed, but due to the page parameters you're setting, it goes beyond the bottom margin of the page.

Don't tinker with `\textwidth`, `\textheight`, `\hoffset` and `\voffset`; use `geometry` instead and specify `a4paper` (or you'd get letter paper that's shorter).

```
\documentclass[leqn]{arabart}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=18cm,height=26cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{arabtex}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs}
 \usepackage{fancybox}
 \novocalize \ligsfalse \setarab
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \ligsfalse \mathchardef\cap="225C \arabfootnotes
 \renewcommand{\l}{\mathscr{L}}
 \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern 2pt
 \newcommand{\supp}{{\rm supp}\;}
 \hfill\rule[2pt]{7truecm}{0.4pt} }
 \newcount\adad \adad=0
 \newcommand{\raqm}{\global\advance\adad by 1{\number\adad}}
\begin{document}    
\textcolor{red}{[1]}    
\newpage     
\LR{hello}     
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to hack around it, but ultimately your layout is very messed up. As the comments said, you are thinkering with `\hoffset` and `\textheight`, and it's throwing the whole thing off.

You can visually see what your layout looks like by using:

```
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}

\layout
```

Somewhere around your code, and you should see something like this:
[image]

I can't quite help you fixing it, since I don't know what you intend your document to look like.

Although, if you for some reason want to leave it as is and just get the page numbers to work, you can just use `\setlength{\footskip}{0mm}`, and that seems to do the trick. (I don't have the rep to show it working, but the page number shows up on the bottom, centered, using your example)

So your code would look like this:

```
\documentclass[leqn]{arabart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\novocalize \ligsfalse \setarab
\textwidth=18truecm
\textheight=26truecm %20.1truecm pour safril2.tex
\hoffset=-4truecm %mmr al-`Ady
\voffset=-3.5truecm \ligsfalse \mathchardef\cap="225C \arabfootnotes
\renewcommand{\l}{\mathscr{L}}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern 2pt
\newcommand{\supp}{{\rm supp}\;}
\hfill\rule[2pt]{7truecm}{0.4pt} }

\newcount\adad \adad=0%134
\newcommand{\raqm}{\global\advance\adad by 1{\number\adad}}

\newcommand{\tmryn}{\begin{arabtext}

$
\shadowbox{\RL{ \bf .hl Alms-'lT}}
$
}

\setlength{\footskip}{0mm} %Add this to your code.

\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{1}

\newpage

\LR{hello}

\end{document}
```